# how to write nested query in bookshelfJS

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

following is sample Db structure

[image]

I want the result in [bookshelfjs](http://bookshelfjs.org/) so that,

1) all columns from campaign table

2) one column which will have count of instances belongs to a campaign

3) one column which will have count of instances belongs to a campaign and having status_id = 3

I know the raw query :

```
 select campaign.*, 
     (select count(*) from instance where instance.campaign_id=campaign.id) as totalInstances,
     (select count(*) from instance where instance.campaign_id=campaign.id and instance.status.id=3) as duplicateInstances 
 from campaign
```

I have tried same query using

```
 qb.select(rawQuery); // rawQuery= above query
```

but no luck. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
knex('campaign').select([
  'campaign.*', 
  (builder) => builder
    .count('*')
    .from('instance')
    .where('instance.campaign_id', knex.raw('??', ['campaign.id']))
    .as('totalInstances'), 
  (builder) => builder
    .count('*')
    .from('instance')
    .where('instance.campaign_id', knex.raw('??', ['campaign.id']))
    .where('instance.status.id', 3)
    .as('duplicateInstances')
]).toSQL()

select 
  "campaign".*, 
  (select count(*) from "instance" where "instance"."campaign_id" = "campaign"."id") as "totalInstances", 
  (select count(*) from "instance" where "instance"."campaign_id" = "campaign"."id" and "instance"."status"."id" = ?) as "duplicateInstances" 
  from "campaign"
```

Comment: Mikael Lepistö, Thanks for the response. The query look fine the only thing is I'm looking for count. its missing. :(

Comment: @AkshayP oops I missed that. I updated the answer with counts.